# Use javascript match to extract parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string such as the one below. I want to extract different parts of the string, the first part I want to grab all characters that are after the prefix MAC_ up to the the word MACHINE_ and then I want to extract the second part which is all characters after MACHINE_.

**String**

```
MAC_00:14:00:00:00:05MACHINE_I50
```

Have tried

```
var id = String(text.match(/MAC_/g));
var device= String(text.match(/MACHINE_/g));
```

But they just give me the text MAC_ and MACHINE_.

Comment: [`MAC_(.*?)MACHINE_(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/vS2dF4/1). Check first and second captured groups.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
/MAC_(.*?)MACHINE_(.*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP1vX7/1)

*Pattern details*:

- `MAC_(.*?)` - `MAC_` and (Group 1) any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first...
- `MACHINE_(.*)` - `MACHINE_` and (Group 2) the rest of the line.

```js
var re = /MAC_(.*?)MACHINE_(.*)/; 
var str = 'MAC_00:14:00:00:00:05MACHINE_I50';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```

Comment: The technique is: match what you do not need, and capture what you need. Moving the `(` and `)` is just a matter of precising the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to take advantage of the fact that javascript's string.match function, when used with a regex that contains groups (parentheses), returns an array in which the first entry is the entire matched string, and the subsequent entries show what each parenthesized piece matched.

```
var teststring = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var index = 0;
var result = teststring.match(/^.*(SP.*t).*(n t).*(pla)/)[index];
```

The following table shows the value of "result" given various values of "index"

0 --> "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the pla"

1 --> "SPAIN st"

2 --> "n t"

3 --> "pla"

4 (and beyond) --> undefined

Because there were 3 groups (3 sets of parentheses), the match returned an array of 4 entries, with the 0'th being the full match and the rest reflecting each separate group.

Here's another example:

```
var teststring = "The 234 chickens, bananas, apples weighed over 205 pounds";
var index = 0;
let result = teststring.match(/^Th.* (chick.*ns,).{5}(.*eighed)[^0-9]*(.*)/)[index]
```

The following table shows the value of "result" given various values of "index"

0 --> The 234 chickens, bananas, apples weighed over 205 pounds

1 --> chickens,

2 --> nas, apples weighed

3 --> 205 pounds

4 (and beyond) --> undefined